# How to group a cluster of points from a set such that it matches the edges of a specific geometric template whose dimensions are know?

Tags: graphics, computational-geometry

Let's say there is cartesian 2D space with many points scattered around. I now have a geometric template as shown in the attached image. I know for sure there are some points in the space that can definitely align with this template's edges. are there any efficient and fast algorithm to find these points?[image]

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, you have to loop on every point of the cluster, match it to some vertex of the template, then find a second point that matches the distance to another vertex of the template. These two points define a rigid transformation, and you can predict the remaining vertices. Then find all remaining matches.

Assuming that you use an efficient data structure that tells a matching point at a known distance in sublinear time D(n), and a matching point at known coordinates in sublinear time P(n), the total cost will be like

```
m.n.(D(n)+(m-2).P(n))
```

where `m` is the number of vertices of the template. (By brute-force, the complexity is m²n².)

Possible data structures include a grid, a kD-tree and a vantage-tree.

[image]

Comment: If multiple matches are possible, the complexity will be higher.